# datetimepicker does not close on selecting date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker and want that the dropdown should close on selecting the date as well as on selecting date n time both. Currently, it does not close in both the cases.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 <span id="datetimepickerStart" class="input-append date">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Start)

 $('#datetimepickerStart).datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        use24hours: true,
        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
        endDate: new Date(),
         autoclose: true,
        changeDate: function () {
            alert();
        }

    });
```

I am converting this span into datetimepicker. I tried using autoclose property, changeDate event but no success. Most of the solutions available are for datepicker and not for datetimepicker.

UPDATE: I was able to handle the change event of datetimepicker but now, 'hide' method does not work correctly. Here is the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/QM8eC/59

Can anyone check now ?

Comment: Which datetimepicker plugin are you using?

Comment: I have mentioned that its bootstrap datetimepicker.

Comment: I don't think you will get it for `datetimepicker` when `time` is enabled as per their docs.. Otherwise `keepOpen` will do the trick..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao :KeepOpen is false by default so how will it help. http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#keepopen

Comment: I believe there is no option for automatically closing the time component, because there is no reliable way to know when the user is finished selecting the time

Comment: Is there any way to detect if date is selected ? I tried change and changeDate event but none of them worked.

Comment: Look at the `linked pickers` example http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but in this example also, the dropdown does not close when date is selected or when date and time both are selected...

Comment: I was able to handle the change event of datetimepicker but now, 'hide' method does not work correctly. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QM8eC/59/

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work.

**In js section**

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker({
        showClose: true,
        icons: {
            close: 'closeText'
        }
    });
});
```

**In css section**

```
 .closeText:before {
        content: "Close";
    }
```

[image]

Follow this site:https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Date-Time-Picker-Bootstrap-4.html